# Where is Scene Editor?

Tags: xcode, scenekit

Once upon a time, when I had created `.scn` file in `XCode` i could edit this file in nice 3D editor. Today I can see only big file icon instead of 3D view. Is something changed? Or my Xcode is somehow broken?

**Check Image:**
[image: Just icon, no 3D editor]

Comment: You should restart Xcode and possibly your computer. You should get the scene kit editor when you select a scene kit file. Unless you somehow have it set to open as some other kind of file by accident (check the file inspector in Xcode to check)

Comment: I did it. Nothing changed. Exactly same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted permanently Godot and restarted computer.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode's project navigator you should be able to right-click on the scn file and then select the desired editor (`Open As` → `SceneKit Document`).

Comment: If I reinstall Godot I will try it!